# El capitan на mac mini 2007

Tags: macos, mac

Можно ли поставить на mac mini 2007 года mac os x el capitan? Процессор Intel Core 2 Duo, 3 GB RAM.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, El Capitan на Mac mini 2007 года не запустится.
Список поддерживаемого оборудования:

- MacBook (модели начала 2015 года);
- MacBook (модели в алюминиевом корпусе конца 2008 года, модели начала
  2009 года или новее);
- MacBook Pro (модели середины/конца 2007 года или новее);
- MacBook Air (модели конца 2008 года или новее);
- Mac mini (модели начала 2009 года или новее);
- iMac (модели середины 2007 года или новее);
- Mac Pro (модели начала 2008 года или новее);
- Xserve (модели начала 2009 года).

Ознакомится с полными требованиями и спецификацией можно [тут](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP728?locale=ru_RU)

Answer (score 0):

Запустится, нужно минимум 2Гб оперативки и патч. Сам проверял, работает!
В качестве подтверждения почитайте информацию в википедии:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini